# Elasticsearch, how to store data per date?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to store daily statistics of sales.

By daily, I mean `day of year`.

Conceptually the data would look like the following.

```
{ 
  name: bmw,
  daily_statics : {
     1: { sold_count: 5},
     2: { sold_count: 3},

  ...
     365: {sold_count: 2}
}
```

I'm trying to create a mapping in `elasticsearch-dsl-py` and having trouble.

I guess it would be similarly troublesome to create a mapping for this document?

- edit

I'd like to view seasonal trend of data. so day-of-year 1 and day-of-year 365 is actually pretty close input point. Besides, I only need one year worth of data

Comment: How are you planning to query your data? Having daily indices is a much better option.

Comment: I'd like to view seasonal trend of data. so day-of-year 1 and day-of-year 365 is actually pretty close input point. 

Besides, I only need one year worth of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let ES generate the mappings for you with the help of [dynamic template path matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch):

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "catch_daily_statistics": {
          "path_match": "daily_statistics.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "sold_count": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But before you proceed with this architectural choice, I'd recommend to first check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633583/8160318) which deals with the difficulties of aggregating on dicts-of-dicts.

It'd be more reasonable to use daily indices as @Evaldas pointed out. But I'd go with [`nested` fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) of the form:

```
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "name": "bmw",
  "daily_stats": [
    {
      "day_date": "2021/01/01",
      "day_iso_num": 1,
      "sold_count": 5
    },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

That way, you'll be able to perform

- [`range` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) on `day_date`
- range and [`term` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on `day_iso_num` (since day-of-year is different year-over-year...)
- and any [`metric` aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics.html) (among others) on `sold_count`