# Elasticsearch aggregation on a field with dynamic properties

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

Given the following mapping where variants are a `nested` type and options is a `flattened` type:

```
{
  "doc_type" : "product",
  "id" : 1,
  "variants" : [
    {
      "options" : {
        "Size" : "XS",
      },
      "price" : 1,
    },

    {
      "options" : {
        "Size" : "S",
        "Material": "Wool"
      },
      "price" : 6.99,
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to run an aggregation that produces data in the following format:

```
{
  "variants.options.Size": {
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "XS",
        "doc_count" : 1
      },
      {
        "key" : "S",
        "doc_count" : 1
      },
    ],
  },
  "variants.options.Material": {
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "Wool",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

I could very easily do something like:

```
"aggs": {
    "variants.options.Size": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variants.options.Size"
      }
    },
    "variants.options.Material": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variants.options.Material"
      }
    }
  }
```

The caveat here is that we're using the `flattened` type for options because the fields in options are **dynamic** and so there is no way for me to know before hand that we want to aggregate on `Size` and `Material`.

Essentially, I want to tell Elasticsearch that it should aggregate on whatever keys it finds under `options`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to tell Elasticsearch that it should aggregate on whatever keys it finds under options. Is there a way to do this?

Not directly. I had [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54198251/8160318) a while back. I haven't found a clean solution to this day and I'm convinced there isn't one.

Luckily, there's a [`scripted_metric`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) workaround that [I outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633583/8160318). Applying it to your use case:

```
POST your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "dynamic_variant_options": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.buckets = [:];",
        "map_script": """
          def variants = params._source['variants'];
          for (def variant : variants) {
            for (def entry : variant['options'].entrySet()) {
              def key = entry.getKey();
              def value = entry.getValue();
              def path = "variants.options." + key;

              if (state.buckets.containsKey(path)) {
                if (state.buckets[path].containsKey(value)) {
                  state.buckets[path][value] += 1;
                } else {
                  state.buckets[path][value] = 1;
                }
              } else {
                state.buckets[path] = [value:1];
              }
            }
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": "return state",
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

would yield:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "dynamic_variant_options" : {
    "value" : [
      {
        "buckets" : {
          "variants.options.Size" : {
            "S" : 1,
            "XS" : 1
          },
          "variants.options.Material" : {
            "Wool" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You'll need to adjust the [`painless`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-guide.html) code if you want the `buckets` to be arrays of key-doc_count pairs instead of hash maps like in my example.