# ElasticSearch | How to create mapping for an object, with key = timestamp and value = list

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, I'm trying to create the mapping for a the following data structure:

```
"timelineData": {
        "1249689600000": [
            {
                /* left out */
            }
        ],
        "1234396800000": [
            {
                /* left out */
            },
            {
                /* left out */
            },
        ]
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
timelineData: {                                 
    properties: {                               
        type: 'nested',                         
        properties: {                           
            /* left out */                            
        }                                       
    }                                           
}
```

Creating the index throws the following error:

```
[mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [{type=text}] declared on field [properties]
```

**Question:** How can I create a ES mapping for the above data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [dynamic mapping template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch):

```
PUT timeline_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "ts_nested": {
          "path_match":   "timelineData.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "timelineData": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Do consider, though, that you may soon hit the issue of having too many keys to keep track of and/or hitting the ES limit on inner fields. Similarly, you'll be limited in terms of accessing the shared attributes of the inner `/* left out */` objects as discussed in [Terms aggregation with nested wildcard path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54198251/8160318).

So I'd suggest the following:

```
{
  "timelineData": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1249689600000,
      "data": [{},{}, ...]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you apply a `date` mapping to the `timestamp`, you'll get the benefit of being able to perform date-range queries & aggs.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. The structure is not viable.