# ElasticSearch aggregating by a nested field with variable nesting (or over particular json field)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following structure `GET /index-*/_mapping`:

```
    "top_field" : {
      "properties" : {
        "dict_key1" : {
          "properties" : {
            "field1" : {...},
            "field2" : {...},
            "field3" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "field4" : {...}
          },
        "dict_key2" : {
          "properties" : {
            "field1" : {...},
            "field2" : {...},
            "field3" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "field4" : {...}
          },
        "dict_key3": ...
        }
```

In other words, `top_field` stores a json.

I would like to aggregate over `'field3.keyword'` regardless of `dict_key*`. Something like `top_field.*.field3.keyword`.

However, I can't get it to work using terms aggregation, with or without nested. I also tried to just to bucket by the different `dict_key*`, which would be almost as good, but I can't get this to work either.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR I had the same problem some time ago ([Terms aggregation with nested wildcard path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54198251/8160318)) and it turns out it's not directly possible due to the way lookups and path accessors are performed.

---

There's a scripted workaround though:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms_emulator": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.keyword_counts = [:]",
        "map_script": """
          def source = params._source['top_field'];
          for (def key : source.keySet()) {
            if (!source[key].containsKey('field3')) continue;
            
            def field3_kw = source[key]['field3'];
        
            if (state.keyword_counts.containsKey(field3_kw)) { 
              state.keyword_counts[field3_kw] += 1;
            } else {
              state.keyword_counts[field3_kw] = 1;
            }
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": "state",
        "reduce_script": "states[0]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding something along the lines of

```
"aggregations" : {
  "terms_emulator" : {
    "value" : {
      "keyword_counts" : {
        "world" : 1,
        "hello" : 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

While this works just fine, I'd disadvise using scripts in production. You could rather restructure your data such that straightforward lookups are possible. For instance:

```
{
  "top_field": {
    "entries": [
      {
        "group_name": "dict_key1",
        "key_value_pairs": {
          "field3": "hello"
        }
      },
      {
        "group_name": "dict_key2",
        "key_value_pairs": {
          "field3": "world"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and make `entries` nested. Maybe even ditch `top_field` since it seems redundant and start directly w/ `entries`.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this and let you know. Unfortunately, `top_field` cannot be ditched because it is part of a collection of other fields - ones that are used in aggregation as well. However, is there no way to simply access the "values" of the {dict_key* : values} pairs as a list and then it would essentially be a nested aggregation. Using your post that you linked: something like `"path": "nested_parent.values()"` or some other way to interface with it.

Comment: And I can now confirm that this does work. I will wait a bit before accepting since there might be a solution out there that does not involve scripting.

Comment: Gotcha. Yea no there's no such interface -- at least not outside of the script context. Plus, whenever the context encounters a `nested` data type, it can only access the 'current' iteration. That's why we had to use `params._source` to gain access to all of the top level doc's attributes, i.e. `"nested_parent.values()"`...

Comment: Ultimately, I got the data structure changed and educated everyone working on our system of proper document design in ES. It seems that arrays of dictionaries are preferred to dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Nice. They certainly are preferred. Good luck with the rest of your implementation!

Comment: Hey @AOK -- I've just launched my [Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/) and I think you'd find it useful!