# Elasticsearch dynamic mapping for object within attribute

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Wondering if I can create a "dynamic mapping" within an elasticsearch index. The problem I am trying to solve is the following: I have a schema that has an attribute that contains an object that can differ greatly between records. I would like to mirror this data within elasticsearch if possible but believe that automatic mapping may get in the way.

Imagine a scenario where I have a schema like the following:

```
{
    name: string
    origin: string
    payload: object // can be of any type / schema
}
```

Is it possible to create a mapping that supports this? I do not need to query the records by this payload attribute, but it would be great if I can.

Note that I have checked the documentation but am confused on if what elastic calls dynamic mapping is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's certainly possible to specify which queryable fields you expect the `payload` to contain and what those fields' mappings should be.

Let's say **each** doc will include the fields `payload.livemode` and `payload.created_at`. If these are the only two fields you'll want to perform queries on, and you'd like to **disable** [dynamic, index-time mappings autogenerated by Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) for the rest of the fields, you can use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) like so:

```json
PUT my-payload-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "variable_payload": {
          "path_match": "payload",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "object",
            "dynamic": false,
            "properties": {
              "created_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "livemode": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "origin": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, as you ingest your docs:

```json
POST my-payload-index/_doc
{
  "name": "abc",
  "origin": "web.dev",
  "payload": {
    "created_at": "2021-04-05 08:00:00",
    "livemode": false,
    "abc":"def"
  }
}

POST my-payload-index/_doc
{
  "name": "abc",
  "origin": "web.dev",
  "payload": {
    "created_at": "2021-04-05 08:00:00",
    "livemode": true,
    "modified_at": "2021-04-05 09:00:00"
  }
}
```

and verify with

```json
GET my-payload-index/_mapping
```

no new mappings will be generated for the fields `payload.abc` nor `payload.modified_at`.

Not only that — the new fields will also be ignored, as per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html):

> These fields will not be indexed or searchable, but will still appear in the `_source` field of returned hits.

*Side note: if fields are neither stored nor searchable, they're effectively the opposite of [`enabled`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html).*

---

#### The Big Picture

Working with variable contents of a single, top-level object is quite standard. Take for instance the stripe [`event` object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object) — each event has an `id`, an `api_version` and a few other shared params. Then there's the `data` object that's analogous to your `payload` field.

Now, all is fine, **until** you need to aggregate on the contents of your `payload`. See, since the content is variable, so are the data paths / accessors. But wildcards in aggregation paths [don't work in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198251/terms-aggregation-with-nested-wildcard-path). Scripts do but are [onerous to maintain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953820/elasticsearch-aggregating-by-a-nested-field-with-variable-nesting-or-over-parti/64954300#64954300).

Back to stripe. They partially solved it through what they call polymorphic, typed hashes — as discussed [in their blog on API design](https://stripe.com/blog/payment-api-design):

[image]

A pretty neat approach that's worth emulating.

---

P.S. I discuss dynamic templates in more detail in the [chapter "Mapping Automation"](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/1-mapping-automation-fc002ac8d9db497db61015bf6a4f3c93) of [my ES Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/).